# Python - IOError: File not open for reading

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to make a program that updates a csv row by the 0-9 range which would be the ID Number. So after it searches for the id number, it prompts the user to enter the replacement values as you can see on the `replace` part of this code below. Since csv is comma separated i connected the strings with comma alongside so it would line up correctly on the bars.  But the problem is. this error: `IOError: File not open for reading` I did line.readlines() before using the loop.  Here's the code by the way.

```
    def update_thing():
        stud_ID = str(ID_num.get())
        stud_name = str(name.get())
        stud_course = str(Crs.get())
        stud_year = str(Yr.get())
        searchID = str(sID_num.get())
        filename = str(files.get())

        replace = stud_ID +','+ stud_name +','+ stud_course +','+ stud_year
        empty = []



        with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
            Swriter = csv.writer(file, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            file.readlines()
            for row in file:
                if row[0:9] == searchID:

                    file.writerow([empty])
                    file.writerow([replace])
                    msg = Label(upd_win, text="Updated Successful", font="fixedsys 12 bold").place(x=3,y=120)

                if not row[0:9] == searchID:
                    msg1 = Label(upd_win, text="Update Failed", font="fixedsys 12 bold").place(x=3,y=120)
```

Thankyou very much for any help you could offer.

Comment: A file that's opened only for writing can't be read from. Try `with open(filename, 'w+') as file` instead.

Comment: @frederick99 `'w+'` is the correct mode for a cache file, rarely necessary in the days of large RAM and virtual memory. @Jed Hart does not want to delete all data in the file, and therefore should not use `w` at all.

Comment: Too late to edit my comment now! As phihag pointed out, using `'w+'` would overwrite the file with an empty file. Use `'r+'` instead. :-)

Comment: @frederick99 thanks for this fred. because of this I have found the reason why it kept deleting it all haha :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fault is in the line

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
```

As [documented](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#open), `open(filename, 'wb')` **will truncate the file to 0 bytes, i.e. delete all of its contents**. In addition, it will be opened write-only.

Instead, open the file with mode `'r+b'`. This allows you to read and write, and the file will not get truncated upon opening.